# Circular button with drawable in the middle

Tags: android, xml, drawable, android-button, material-components-android

I'm currently making the layout of an app I'm working on and I'm not able to create this button in xml.

[image: Circular Button]

The arrow inside is a .png picture (I can also get it exported as vector) and the background is just a drawable. I am unable to mix this two assets to make this button. My current result is this:

[image: Bad circular button]

The xml is:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/onboardingStep2NextButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/onboardingStep2SubTitle"
    android:src="@drawable/long_left"
    android:background="@drawable/purple_round_background"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

purple_round_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <corners  android:radius="50dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/purple" />
</shape>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Note that using a AppCompatImageView you don't have a ripple like a Button.

Comment: Okay! Thanks. I don't know if my client wants this button to have a ripple but if I need it I will change it to your solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `android:padding` may help you:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/onboardingStep2NextButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/onboardingStep2SubTitle"
    android:src="@drawable/long_left"
    android:background="@drawable/purple_round_background"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a **`MaterialButton`**:

```
   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.IconOnly"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle"
        />
```

with this style:

```
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.IconOnly" >
    <item name="iconPadding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">12dp</item>
    <item name="iconGravity">textStart</item>
</style>
```

and this `shapeAppearanceOverlay`:

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add android:padding="" to your AppCompatImageView